# How to make a label blink

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer

I have a `Stopwatch` in my form with `Interval = 1000` displayed in the `hh:mm:ss` format.

When it reaches the 5th second it should start to blink the label background as green but so far I can only make the background color turn to green without any flash.

This is how I turn the background color to green:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Text = SW.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
    If Label1.Text = "00:00:05" Then
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Green
    End If
End Sub
```

How do I make the label blink?

Comment: Slight note, I don't think you set the `Stopwatch` interval to 1000, I think you mean you did this to the `Timer`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a simple `Async` method to do this.

The following code will give `Label1` the effect of flashing. Since we have used `While True` this will continue indefinitely once you hit "00:00:05".

```
Private Async Sub Flash()
    While True
        Await Task.Delay(100)
        Label1.Visible = Not Label1.Visible
    End While
End Sub
```

You would call this inside your `Timer1_Tick` method:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Text = SW.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
    If Label1.Text = "00:00:05" Then
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Green
        Flash()
    End If
End Sub
```

*If* you only want to flash a couple of times we can make a simple change to `Flash()`:

```
Private Async Sub Flash()
    For i = 0 To 10
        Await Task.Delay(100)
        Label1.Visible = Not Label1.Visible
    Next

    'set .Visible to True just to be sure
    Label1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

By changing the number 10 to a number of your choice you can shorten or lengthen the time taken to flash. I have added in `Label1.Visible = True` *after* the `For` loop just to be sure that we see the `Label` once the flashing has finished.

> You will have to import `System.Threading.Tasks` to make use of `Task.Delay`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a label, two textboxes, and a button.
The screen allows you to 'set' a couple of colours - this could be taken further, by adding an Error colour, a Warning colour (where you haven't filled a field in...?) and more.
This colour selection would, in a real application, be done by an admin person, from a separate screen, and stored in the DB.
The timer frequency would also be set in the Admin screen/function.
This particular screen needs the textboxes to be double-clicked, and a colour selected for each one.
The back colour for each box changes. Then press the Start button.
If you press the Start button again, it toggles the timer (on/off)

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
' not quite correct for what I want, but close...
' https://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/368433-blinking-text
Me.Label1.Text = "A blinking text box"
Me.Label1.BackColor = TextBox2.BackColor
End Sub

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If Me.Label1.BackColor = TextBox2.BackColor Then
        Me.Label1.BackColor = TextBox1.BackColor
    Else
        Me.Label1.BackColor = TextBox2.BackColor
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseDoubleClick
    Dim dlg As New ColorDialog()
    If dlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox1.BackColor = dlg.Color
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.MouseDoubleClick
    Dim dlg As New ColorDialog()
    If dlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox2.BackColor = dlg.Color
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = Not Timer1.Enabled
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Try to put something like this in Timer1_Tick event handler -

```
Label1.Visible = Not Label1.Visible
```

Set the timer to enabled and it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the color when the Text is *00:00:05* then you should also specify what the `Backcolor` should be when the text is something else i.e *00:00:06*

Try this and see if it works:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
Label1.Text = SW.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
If Label1.Text = "00:00:05" Then
    Label1.BackColor = Color.Green
else
    Label1.Backcolor = Color.Yellow '(Change color as needed)
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private blinkingTimer As New Timer()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Set Timer
        blinkingTimer.Interval = 500 ' Time to keep blinking in milliseconds
        AddHandler blinkingTimer.Tick, AddressOf BlinkLabel

        ' Start Timer
        blinkingTimer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BlinkLabel(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red Then
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black
        Else
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        ' Stop timer when app is closed
        blinkingTimer.Stop()
    End Sub
End Class
```